# How can we select all CustomerNum from a subquery that filters by OrderDesc?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select specific OrderDesc from a table, which represent a smaller dataset, and based on the OrderDesc returned, I want to select a larger data set, based on CustomerNum.

Here is my hacked together code:

```
Drop Table Order_Table

SELECT *
INTO Order_Table
FROM (VALUES
   (001,          456,       'repair',       'House'),
   (002,          456,        'paint',       'House'),
   (003,          678,        'repair',      'Fence'),
   (004,          789,        'repair',      'House'),
   (005,          789,        'paint',       'House'),
   (006,          789,        'repair',      'Fence'),
   (007,          789,        'paint',       'Fence')
   )
v (orderNum,    CustomerNum, OrderDesc,   Structure)


Select * 
From Order_Table

-- not working here
Select t.*
From (
Select * 
From Order_Table
Where OrderDesc IN ('repair')) t
```

First step, get this.

```
CustomerNum
456
678
789
```

Second step, get this.

```
orderNum    CustomerNum OrderDesc   Structure
1           456         repair      House
3           678         repair      Fence
4           789         repair      House
5           789         paint       House
6           789         repair      Fence
7           789         paint       Fence
```

Comment: I'm confused... What is the business reason that caused order number 2 to be excluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want all orders for all customers that have at least one "repair" order:

```
SELECT *
FROM order_table AS o1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM order_table AS o2
    WHERE o2.CustomerNum = o1.CustomerNum AND o2.OrderDesc IN ('repair')
)
```

Comment: All set now! Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1):

Correlated subquery is what you're after I believe.

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM ORDER_TABLE A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM ORDER_TABLE B 
              WHERE A.OrderNum = B.OrderNum 
                and B.OrderDesc in ('repair')
```

What you return from the subquery is irrelevant as all that matters is the ordernumber is in the subset defined by the subquery; which will only be those order numbers which contain an order description of 'repair'  The exists simply returns a "TRUE" or "FALSE" so the selected columns are irrelevant; there is debate weather 1 or * is faster/better; I've never spent the time to evaluate which is which and it may vary based on RDBMS so ... "shrug"

More on this from MSFT Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15#exists

The use of 'exists' over 'IN' is one of scalability and handling of NULL.  In doesn't handle Null; exists will.  'in' scalability lacks performance vs exists to my knowledge.